# CIS droids become progressively more human?

Tags: star-wars

The CIS droids in the *Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace* come off as cold, emotionless and what we typically think as "robots" but in *Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith* it seems they have progressed in terms of becoming more "human" in a sense (screaming as being sliced by a light saber or screaming as being blown out into space).

Is there any in-universe reason for this or is it simply for the audience?

Comment: Always assumed that it had something to do with the control ship in the first movie. In Phantom Menace they are more like remote controlled drones but in the later movies and the Clone Wars series they seem to have made them more autonomous.

Comment: My take was what they call in the OGRE Cyberatnk game universe "The Descartes Revolution" As Boelabaal points out, the later CIS droids are made autonomous from Cotrol Ships, and as with teh cybertanks, the more independent thinking they are able to do, the more self-awareness and intellect develops, and thus personality begins to grow. 
As for pain reception, that seems a little . . . sadistic on the part of designers working of 'cannon-fodder' war droids, or perhaps it's the Third Law - prevent droids being harmed by making an incentive not to *be* harmed? Cost effectively?

Comment: imagine splashing out the cash to upgrade your droid to scream when in pain...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The models shown in TPM were [OOM-series](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/OOM-series_battle_droid) which are described as being smarter than the initial batch of B1's. The B1's were mass produced to eventually replace the OOM-series for the Clone Wars.

As to why the B1's behaved the way they did, this if from [their article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/B1_battle_droid#Performance) on Wookieepedia:

> Although the earlier generations were entirely dependent on Central
>   Control Computers, post-Naboo models were retrofitted with cognitive
>   models that allowed independent thought, and featured a greater degree
>   of independence and personality. However, labored with more and more
>   specialized roles that pushed the limits of their programming, many
>   older droids developed personality quirks and a tendency to
>   excessively comment on their situations in an attempt to handle the
>   data overflow that had strained their old logic modules.

In case you are wondering why the B1's weren't all that smart in general, [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51635/why-are-the-b-1-battle-droids-in-the-star-wars-prequels-and-the-clone-wars-2008) is a good post on the subject.